# How to rename UVs of all the objects?

Tags: uv

I am working with multiple objects that have different UV names, I would like to know if there is a quick solution for renaming UVs of all the objects to UVMap

Comment: I don't know of any way besides python..

Comment: I wrote an add-on to handle these types of situations: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Name-Panel-1-5

Comment: Also, I'd add to Chebhou's script, you can iterate them.
I just named mine after the object they belonged to. import bpy for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects : for uvmap in obj.data.uv_layers : uvmap.name = obj.data.name

Answer (score 17, accepted):

select all objects and run the script :

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    
    try:
        obj.data.uv_layers.data.uv_layer_stencil.name = 'UVmap'
    except:    
        continue
```

Comment: This code saved me from having to manually rename the UVs on about 50 different objects by hand, lol